# custom docker action not working with nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, github-actions, building-github-actions

I have been trying to setup a GitHub Action that runs a single node script (called index.js). When GitHub Actions then runs the container after building it, it automatically sets the working directory to /github/workspace, which is why I have replicated this in my Dockerfile ( WORKDIR /github/workspace/ ).

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/github/workspace/index.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:9[8](https://github.com/Sonichigo/GitHub-Action-s/actions/runs/7500548232/job/20419453468#step:3:9)5:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:4[9](https://github.com/Sonichigo/GitHub-Action-s/actions/runs/7500548232/job/20419453468#step:3:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.[11](https://github.com/Sonichigo/GitHub-Action-s/actions/runs/7500548232/job/20419453468#step:3:12).0
```

This suggests that the file does not exist. The debug output I added when building the container shows me otherwise though (root directory shortened for legibility)

I tried copying the index.js file to /github/workspace/index.js in the container, it will be in the correct location when the GitHub Action runs, but it still doesn't work! Instead I get different error!
This is my docker file:-

```
FROM node:lts

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY index.js /github/workspace/index.js
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/github/workspace/index.js"]

RUN ls
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "/github/workspace/index.js"]
```

This fix throws `Error: Resource not accessible by integration`